# Compare two columns in same sheet and find difference

Tags: excel

Hi I have an excel sheet with two columns- A and B. Each column has similar data and B has more data than A. How can I spot data which are available in B but not present in A?

**A 12    13   14    15** and 
B 12  123   13  14   145   15  16

Comment: I guess you mean __available in B but not present in A?__

Comment: Yes. Sorry I typed wrong.available in B but not present in A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CountIf() or Vlookup(). Put in cell C2 this formula `=countif(A:A,B2)` and copy it down. You'll see 0 when they are unique.